# Using MNIST TensorFlow example code for training a network with my own image dataset

Tags: image, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network, mnist

I have just begun to use TensorFlow in python. I want to build a binary image classifier using CNN.

I found an example code on the internet: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py
The explanation is given here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros
This code builds a small Neural Network and uses the MNIST dataset to train and test it.

I roughly understood the working of the CNN but I didn't understand the code line by line.

I want to use the same code with my own Dataset of Images (for both training and testing). In the example the input images are converted into mx784, where m is the number of training/testing examples and 784 comes from flattened images of size 28x28 each. I have converted all my images into an array of size mx1024 using a python script and Similarly converted the ground truth into an array of size mx1. I have stored them into text file as X.txt and y.txt.

Now in the code I have changed the dimensions according to my image dimensions. However, I am confused how to feed the images into the network. Is there a way out other than going through the code line by line? I will be very grateful if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Get Started is just great to understand line by line and to go "deeper" into neural networks step by step.

https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/

Try to understand it, it will really help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much @A. Piro. The link you provided is the same place from where I learned whatever I know about TensorFlow.

I think I should rather understand myself line by line as you said. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes I made my first step in practical machine learning with this like 3 months ago so I know what you are going throught ;) but this tuto is just awesome !

Comment: I have gone through the code and I believe I understood most of it. I have been able to run my images by tweaking the same example code to suit my particular requirement.

However, I can see two abnormalities:
1) The accuracy in general increases but fluctuates at every step (doesn't decrease at every step)
2) The accuracy after 500 steps goes to nan.

I can guess one possible reason - The MNIST example code was meant to work with Black and White Images. However, my images are Grayscale.